# get multiple colums into text file

Tags: python-3.x, file, csv

I have a CSV file and I want to convert it to a text file based on the first column which is the ids. and then each file contain multiple columns. for example

```
file.csv
id  val1 val 2 val3
1    50   52    60
2    45   84    96
```

and etc.
here is my code:

```
  dir_name = '/Users/user/My Documents/test/'
      with io.open('file1.csv', 'rt',encoding='utf8') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
       next(reader)
       xx = []
       for row in reader:
         with open(os.path.join(dir_name, row[0] + ".txt"),'a') as f2:
            xx = row[1:2]
            f2.write(xx +"\n")
```

so it should be:

```
1.text
50   52    60
2.text
45   84    96
```

but it only creates files without content.
can anyone help me?. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of issues:

1. It's actually a whitespace separated values file, not a comma-separated values file. So, you have to change the delimiter from `,`. Also, the whitespace is repeated, so you can pass an additional flag to the `csv` module.
2. Some funkiness with the array indexing and conversion to string.

This program meets your requirements:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import io
import csv
import os

dir_name = './'
with io.open('input.csv', 'rt',encoding='utf8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=' ')
    next(reader)
    xx = []
    for row in reader:
        filename = os.path.join(dir_name, row[0]) 
        with open(filename + ".txt", 'a') as f2:
            xx = row[1:]
            f2.write(" ".join(xx) +"\n")
```